# FTP in C# in a WinForms app times out

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

I have an FTP server from which I pull and parse data and download images.  I've never had an issue pulling text files (my data) but there are 2 directories that I pull images from and one works without a hitch using code identical to below (though obviously with a different Uri and image name array).  In order to get a list of the images I have a function which pulls another file and returns an array of the image names and then I put this array of image names sequentially on the end of a base URI in a loop to download all images.

The code at the bottom is my function for pulling the text file with the image names.  It has it's own URI and comes from a different part of the directory structure.  The interesting thing is that if I manually create an array of images in a known location and feed my image pull code, it works fine but if I run this array building FTP function my image pulls  timeout in the GetResponse() line.  I've shortened the timeout so I don't have to wait so long for it to fail but it's not too short since as I said it works fine with a hard coded list of image URIs.  I've searched here and tried several things thinking I wasn't releasing resources correctly but I cannot figure out what's happening.

Sorry I'm not an expert at this but I have lots of similar code in this app and this is the first time I've had trouble with FTPing.

One note, I have an earlier version of this app which works fine but I must admit I have been very lax in my source version control and don't have the old code (doh!).  I changed something that is now killing it.

```
            //Open a web request based on the URI just built from user selections
            FtpWebRequest imageRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUri);
            imageRequest.UsePassive = false;
            imageRequest.UseBinary = true;
            imageRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            imageRequest.Timeout = 2000;
            //Act on that webrequest based on what the user wants to do (i.e. list a directory, list file, download, etc)
            imageRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            try
            {
                //Now get the response from the tool as a stream.
                FtpWebResponse imageResponse = (FtpWebResponse)imageRequest.GetResponse();
                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Stream imageResponseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(newPath + @"\" + templateImageArray2[x].Split(' ')[0], FileMode.Create);
                int ReadCount = imageResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (ReadCount > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
                    ReadCount = imageResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                fs.Close();
                imageResponseStream.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException r)
            {
                if (r.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                {
                    //Obtain more detail on error:
                    var response = (FtpWebResponse)r.Response;
                    FtpStatusCode errorCode = response.StatusCode;
                    string errorMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
                    //goto RETRY;
                }
                MessageBox.Show(r.Message);
                break;
            }




      string[] tempIDPText = new string[0];
      Uri fileUriLocal = new Uri("ftp://srvrname:password@" + tempIpAddress + "/%2fROOT/DEVICE/HD/" + comboClass.Text + "/data/" + dirName1 + "/" + dirName2 + ".img");
      //Open a web request based on the URI just built from user selections
      FtpWebRequest requestLocal = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUriLocal);
      requestLocal.UsePassive = false;
      requestLocal.UseBinary = true;
      requestLocal.KeepAlive = false;
      //Act on that webrequest based on what the user wants to do (i.e. list a directory, list file, download, etc)
      requestLocal.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
      try
      {
          //Now get the response from the tool as a stream.
          FtpWebResponse responseLocal = (FtpWebResponse)requestLocal.GetResponse();
          Stream responseStream = responseLocal.GetResponseStream();
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

          //Now read an individual file and fill the array with the chamber status
          int y = 0;
          while (!reader.EndOfStream)
          {
              if (reader.EndOfStream)
                  break;
              else
              {
                  Array.Resize(ref tempIDPText, tempIDPText.Length + 1);
                  tempIDPText[tempIDPText.Length - 1] = reader.ReadLine();
              }
          }

          reader.Close();
          responseStream.Close();
          responseLocal.Close();
          ServicePoint srvrPoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(fileUriLocal);
          MethodInfo ReleaseConns = srvrPoint.GetType().GetMethod
                  ("ReleaseAllConnectionGroups",
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
          ReleaseConns.Invoke(srvrPoint, null);
      }

      catch (WebException r)
      {
          //Obtain more detail on the error;
          var response = (FtpWebResponse)r.Response;
          FtpStatusCode errorCode = response.StatusCode;
          string errorMessage = response.StatusDescription;
          MessageBox.Show(errorCode.ToString());
          MessageBox.Show("When getting file Dates: " + errorMessage.ToString());
      }         

      return tempIDPText;
```

Comment: Please try to set UsePassive = true. If this doesn't help try to access via IP-Adress instead of Servername. Maybe the name could not be resolved correctly.

Comment: Yes, do as @Sebi suggests. Or do you have a (really good) reason to use the active mode?

Comment: Passive mode ...  actually that has solved some other problems for me before but in this case it didn't help.  Excellent suggestion though, don't know why I hadn't thought to try that one.

Comment: As for the servername reference, I actually replaced the real name of the server and password to avoid any hint of IP issues.  I use this same FTP access URI in other parts of the code and it works fine.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  I think I'm going to extract this section out into it's own project to make it smaller and make sure it's only this code that's causing my problem.   The hunt goes on :).

Comment: Okay, I tried to use passive mode (this has helped me in some places where my McAfee thinks I have a port scanning virus :))  but I use active mode in this same way to access the same FTP server with no problems.  Also it didn't help.

Comment: Mr @Sebi, in drilling down even further into this problem I seem to have it nailed down to a single line of code.  If I eliminate the Readline() function that reads each line of the file into my array by commenting it out and then manually build the identical array later, I can get it to work and download the images in the array.  I leave every other line in the tempIDPText downloading code except the one that does the Readline into the stream.  I do this same thing in several other places with no issue.

Comment: Oops, I found the tied up resource in a function call that I hadn't noticed.  It had opened another filestream to check for the existence of the file but didn't close it.  Once I closed the filestream I was golden.  Thanks.